# JQuery: addClass not working on element with multiple classes. Why? I'm puzzled!

Tags: jquery, class, element, addclass

This is very frustrating. This is part of some code written for a form.  The input element that is associated with a validation error should display a red border. It works with the *.css* method, but I'd be grateful if someone could show me why the *.addClass* method isn't working.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .field_error{color:red;}
    .red_border{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.field_error').siblings().addClass('red_border');
    });
</script>
...
<label class="description" for="element_1">Email Address </label>
            <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text"/> 
                {% if form.email.errors %}
                    <div class="field_error">{{form.email.errors}}</div>

                {% endif %}
                     </div>

                      ..etc..
```

**If assign "element_1" only one class, it works just fine.**

I can also do this instead:

```
$('.field_error').siblings().css("border", "1px solid red");
```

However, I plan on adding a lot of content to the class I will add.  **Is there a way to get the addClass method to work?**

Thanks!!

Matt

### IMPORTANT EDIT

I forgot to add in the multiple classes on my code. No wonder some people are confused.  Please review code again.

```
<input id="element_1" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text"/>
```

### Solved

The problem was that I had css file that defined the borders of the text input element already.  Fixed now. Thanks to all who brain stored with me.

Comment: Are you writing HTML 5? If not, `<style>` should be `<style type="text/javascript">`

Comment: If you use class names without the underscores does it work?

Comment: @George Cummins - I am quite sure you meant `<style type="text/css">` or `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Ah, yes.  I was editing to add that as you were replying. :)

Comment: @JAAuld: I was wrong, but in a different way. Should be `<script type="text/javascript">` (Assuming Matt is using HTML < 5).

Comment: @George Cummins and @JAAuld: I am indeed building an HTML5 application.  But, I appreciate the insightful remarks.  I'll start adding that to my code in the future to avoid any confusions. :) On the other hand, please review my code.  I totally forgot something that makes my question for relevant.

Comment: Based on your solution, allow me to suggest that you use tools like Firebug and Google Chrome Developer Tools to look "under the hood" at the DOM to see if your class is actually being applied. If you see the class on the element in the DOM, then you know it is a CSS issue and not an issue with the JS. Glad you have it fixed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/KPckC/1/ (*updated with your multiple class correction*)

You do have a typo in your code, though:

```
<input id="element_1" name="email" class="element type="text"/>
```

should be

```
<input id="element_1" name="email" class="element" type="text"/>
```

Maybe that exists in your live site?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist on my live site.  I just truncated my code so that it would be more readable. ;)

Comment: Oh yeah! And I'm glad you pointed that out.  I totally forgot to add the most important part in - the multiple classes for that element!! ahh!

Comment: Yeah, I figured.  Not sure what to tell you, though.  The code you gave us works in my fiddle.  Have you tried making the correction suggested by George Cummins in the comments to your question?

Comment: With the multiple classes?  Yes, see my edited answer--new link to updated code.

Comment: @JAAulde I'm glad it appears to be working fine on js fiddle. And yes, I did use George's suggestion. Strange. Is there any reason why it wouldn't be working with the way I've setup my coding? It still doesn't work on my live site.

Comment: Wihthout being able to see what is actually being generated and presented to the browser, I really can't go much further.

Comment: @JAAulde It's alright.  I appreciate your help. I did figure it out eventually.